# Can the form of the wave equation be determined from the form of its solutions?

Tags: waves, differential-equations

I was taught in high school that the one dimensional wave equation must have the form

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}
$$

And the way to prove this is to claim that a traveling wave must have the form

$$
\psi(x,t)=\psi(x\pm ct)
$$

where $c$ is speed of the wave.

In that case, any equation in this form

$$
\frac{\partial^{2n} \psi}{\partial x^{2n}} = \frac{1}{c^{2n}} \frac{\partial^{2n} \psi}{\partial t^{2n}}
$$
must also be a wave equation.

Is this statement correct?

Comment: Check the derivation of the wave equation.

Comment: If you are just asking if $\psi(x,t)=\psi(x\pm ct)$ solves your proposed equation, then you can easily verify this by just plugging $\psi(x,t)=\psi(x\pm ct)$ into your proposed equation.

Comment: The way you say you were taught to prove it is wrong. More likely, you are misremembering. The fact that $\psi(x\pm ct)$ is a solution was probably mentioned, but not claimed as the proof. In any case, physical models do not even *have* proofs. You can, however, derive the wave equation by, for example, considering small vibrations of a taut string using Newtonian mechanics.